# Class of Successor ordinals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I understand fairly well why the class of all of the ordianls is not a set, because if we assume by contradiction that it is a set, then as an ordinal - we get that it contains itself - which it is a contradiction.

However, why is the class of all the successor ordinals isnt a set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways to show this:

- Probably the most natural is to apply the **replacement axiom (scheme)**: considering the formula "$x$ is the predecessor of $y$" we see that if the class of successor ordinals were a set, then the class of all ordinals would also be a set.
- We could "close downwards" via the **axiom of union**: can you show that if $S$ is a set of ordinals then $\bigcup S$ is the set of all ordinals smaller than some element of $S$? Now think about the downwards closure of the class of successor ordinals.
- We could consider the class of successor ordinals itself as a well-ordering with respect to "$\in$" - if it were a set it would have to be in bijection with some ordinal, but at the same time we can show that the class of successor ordinals is order-isomorphic to the class of ordinals (consider $\alpha+1\mapsto\alpha$).
- In the $\mathsf{ZF}$-style context, we can just observe that for every ordinal $\alpha$ there is a successor ordinal not in $V_\alpha$ - and so the class of successor ordinals isn't a set since every set lies in some $V_\alpha$.

Comment: So, I define $p(x):\exists y\;\text{such that}\;y=x\cup\{x\}\;$ now obviously p is a function because each ordinal has its own unique successor. If I denote the class of all successor ordinals as $A$ and assume that it is infact a set, I get that $p[A] = Ord$ is a set, which is a contradiction. Is this formal enough?

Comment: @GoodWilly Your $p$ isn't a function, it's a formula; you want $p(x,y): y=x\cup\{x\}$, which defines the function sending each ordinal $y$ to its predecessor $x$ (actually you probably want to swap $x$ and $y$ to match the phrasing in the replacement axiom). But yes, that's broadly right.

Comment: Lets say I define $p(y,x): y=x\cup\{x\}$ as a function. 
How will I actually get the limit ordinals from $p[A]\;$ ? which ordinal in A will give me $\omega$ for example by using p?

Comment: @GoodWilly $\omega+1$: we have $\omega+1=\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ so $p(\omega+1,\omega)$ holds. Although again it will be better to swap $x$ and $y$, since this matches how we think of those variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem:** A class $C$ of ordinals is a set iff it has an upper bound.

Proof:

If $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $C$, then all elements of $C$ are elements of $\alpha+1$, as that is the set of all ordinals $\le\alpha$. Therefore $C=\{x\in\alpha+1: x\in C\}$, which by the axiom of separation is a set.

On the other hand, if $C$ is a set, then by the axiom of union, the union of its elements is a set, too. But if $C$ is unbounded, that union is the class of all ordinals, which is proper. Therefore $C$ has to be proper as well. $\square$

---

Now it is easily seen that the class of successor ordinals is unbounded: Assuming that $\alpha$ is an upper bound, then $\alpha+1$ is a successor ordinal larger than the upper bound, contradicting the assumption.

Since the class of successor ordinals is unbounded, it is proper.